# Code to reverse words in a String using StringBuffer

Tags: java, string, reverse, stringbuffer

This is some code for reversing characters in a string using `StringBuffer`:

```
String sh = "ABCDE";
System.out.println(sh + " -> " + new StringBuffer(sh).reverse());
```

Is there any similar way to reverse words in a string using `StringBuffer`?

Input: "I Need It" and 
Output should be: "It Need I"

Comment: Only stringbuffer is acceptable?

Comment: Other solutions are also welcome.String Buffer will be more useful.

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer as it was replaced by StringBuilder more than ten years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [`StringUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) [`reverseDelimited`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#reverseDelimited(java.lang.String,%20char)):

> Reverses a String that is delimited by a specific character.
>   The Strings between the delimiters are not reversed. Thus java.lang.String becomes String.lang.java (if the delimiter is '.').

So in your case we will use space as a delimiter:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
String reversed = StringUtils.reverseDelimited(sh, ' ');
```

You may also find a more lengthy solution without it [here](http://java67.blogspot.co.il/2015/06/how-to-reverse-words-in-string-java.html).

Comment: Thanks. First one is better than longer one.

Answer (score 1):

Using only JDK methods

```
String input = "I Need It";

String[] array = input.split(" ");
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(array);
Collections.reverse(list);
String output = String.join(" ", list);

System.out.println(output);
```

And result is `It Need I`